# how can we improve message authenticity in ad-hoc networks , without using traditional methods of encryption and digital signatures

Tags: encryption, functional-programming, ecdsa

usually we are using public-key encryption, or functional encryption along with ECDSA signatures to provide message authenticity and integrity  in Ad-hoc networks, but both these techniques have inherent drawbacks, what else can we use to improve the message authenticity and integrity in ad-hoc networks.

Comment: are there any constraints besides ad-hoc networks, like none of the comunicating parties had contact before, no trusted third party, etc?

Comment: i am asking this with respect to Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks, so these constraints are the part of VANET, communicating nodes will be V2V or V2I, and there will be a trusted authority also.

Answer (score 0):

regarding "without using traditional methods of encryption and digital signatures", i can not say the following more clearly:

STOP ... right here... right now ...
when we are talking about vehicular data exchange the cryptographic needs are mission critical. when you ask about what can be done *without* well established methods, you are thinking about breaking rule number one in cryptography: designing your own system.

you do not want your own crypto system / protocol ... you want a well tested, reliable, publicly available, system that has been audited by the crypto community

Comment: thanks sir. could you suggest me if i am using encryption in VANET, and i want to use, Hidden Vector Encryption, instead of public key encryption and identity based encryption. how can i compare the performance of IBE and HVE.